# Beethoven spelling a D#7 chord with a G-natural in 2nd movement of Emperor Concerto -- why?

Tags: notation, chord-theory

In Beethoven's Emperor Piano Concerto, 2nd movement, there is an unusual spelling -- normally I'd expect the G-natural in the 1st violins in the 7th measure (top right of the image) to be spelled as a F-double-sharp; the same spelling is used later in the movement when the piano has the same melody and chords.

[image]

And also in the master's handwriting...
[image]

Do we know why Beethoven might have decided to spell it this way?

One reason I'm asking is it reminds me of the unusual pitch spelling in his 5th Symphony 1st movement, where the flutes and 1st violins alternate between D-flats and C-sharps respectively; there I see it as the composer wanting to emphasize that the two groups of instruments are still having a dialog despite the fragmentation of the motif.

EDIT: He seems to be doing it with a vengeance: in the fragment below, where we have Flute, Clarinet in A, Bassoon, and Piano, notice that the clarinet, being a transposing instrument, actually has the "correct" spelling, whereas the 3 other instruments, flute, bassoon, and piano, all have F#-G-G# -- it looks as if there's something special about these three notes, but I'm not sure how one would figure out the mystery...

[image]

Comment: I would guess he thought he could go either way and decided that the G natural would be easier to read.

Comment: @Peter - I was about to assume that until I found the E sharp in the viola part in Bar 3. Maybe Beethoven really didn't feel like using double sharp signs?

Comment: Why would it be more logical to be an F double sharp? I have very little theoretical knowledge; I know what double sharps are, but I don't understand enough yet to know when to use one.

Comment: @Creynders - Write a D#7 chord with all the proper interval sizes (e.g. write a major 3rd instead of a diminished 4th between the root and the 3rd). You'll write an F double sharp instead of a G natural.

Comment: I for sure don't have a confident answer but—maybe this is one of those times that it's better to think of those three beats as two chords connected by passing motion than to "name" the middle chord? The downbeat is BM; the third beat is presumably G#m (with the 5th missing). The 2nd beat is certainly a D# *something*; the motion of the bass tonicizes the G#. But the violins are just "passing." The viola even misses the opportunity to provide the 5th, an A# (insert joke about boring viola parts).

Comment: But ultimately I think the answer would be "This is by far not the first time that Beethoven, or other 19th-century composers, uses the "wrong" enharmonic spelling just because it's easier for him or the performer." Aldwell & Schachter weren't around to rap his knuckles.

Comment: @AndyBonner - Any answer that explains both the use of G -> G# in Bar 7 and E# -> E in Bar 3, then? That's the main conundrum preventing me from answering - assuming that Beethoven either didn't know or hated double sharps feels lame, especially with no evidence.

Comment: @Dekkadeci Well, [he did know](https://www.reddit.com/r/piano/comments/71ed1v/in_terms_of_theory_why_does_beethoven_use_a/)...

Comment: @AndyBonner I did consider a melodically-influenced choice of spelling, but typically when choosing how to spell due to melody rather than harmony, one sharps notes when going up, and flattens notes when going down; whereas here Beethoven flattened a note in an ascending motion.

Comment: @Dekkadeci One another popular reason to misspell that is not the case here, is when dealing with an open string -- it's very strange to write an F3-double-sharp instead of a G3-natural for the lowest note on the violin; but again, this is a G4 which is not an open string; and the manuscript piano part also has the G-natural; I don't know if there's a similar reason for wind instruments or for transposing instruments; I just found another fragment that might be relevant I'm adding to the original post ....

Comment: @Gabi - If the A clarinet is anything like the ones I play, the B is above the break while the A# is below, so the use of A# in the notation may be to emphasize that it's still below the break.

Comment: We see that Beethoven used both the "right" spelling (on the clarinet) and the "wrong" spelling (on the flute and bassoon) at the same time. I would regard this as evidence that he was thinking chromatically and didn't care about the formal correctness of one spelling over the other.

Comment: Remember how BACH would sign his name with B-A-C-H... that's because those are german speaking names for notes.

While there is no difference between F sharp and Fis in the pitch, the german system is better suited to spelling words, thanks to the extra "H". AESCH, FISCHE, etc.

Maybe he was grafitti-ing some word. FISGEGIS?. Maybe with a different clef... AISHAHIS? Anyway, there are lots of real examples in the literature...

Comment: @Gabi it's not a simple case of up motion = sharp, down motion = flat. You would not write A-Ab-G-Gb-F-E in A-minor would you?

Comment: Is the passage in F# minor? If so then G natural could be related to a bIII or N6 chord

Comment: Also E# is the correct way to make the V chord major in F# minor. Even if he’s not going to F# minor he could be borrowing from it. Third chord of the third measure of the first excerpt is a secondary dominant which explains the E#. (V7/vi)

Comment: @ToddWilcox the E sharp is correct because it's the third of V/V in B major, a C sharp major chord.  The G natural should be an F double sharp because it's the third of V7/vi, so the leading tone to a G sharp minor chord.

Comment: @Dekkadeci, "E# -> E in Bar 3" for just that one, it could be spelled that way to maintain parallel thirds between viola and cello.

Comment: @AndyBonner in 1809 it might have been the first time or at least close to the first time.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that it is easier for the performer to read.

But another, more intriguing answer to this puzzle is that the construction of harmony was not reliant on block chords until more than a century after Beethoven.

Beethoven (and his contemporaries) would have thought of those excerpts as being contrapuntal, each instrument acting as its own musical line.

Thinking one musical line at a time, aka looking at the score "horizontally", the accidentals you describe are normal convention for displaying a rising chromatic pattern. It is easier for the musician reading the music to see a G in that position rather than an F##.

However if we think "vertically", and look at how all the crotchets line up on every beat as a defined chord, that G should indeed be F## to fit inside a D#7 chord.

But this was not Beethoven's thought process.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't much of an answer. More of a comment about the "sharps for rising chromatic lines" practice.

In Mozart's Fantasia in C minor, K.475 there is a chromatic scale over an `F7` chord resolving to `Bb`...

[image]

...the rising chromatic line does not always follow the practice of using sharps.

That's from https://imslp.org/wiki/Fantasia_in_C_minor%2C_K.475_(Mozart%2C_Wolfgang_Amadeus), first edition, the monograph doesn't actually notate the complete line.

The segment `A♮ B♭ B♮` rather than `A♮ A♯ B♮` makes sense because it's moving to a tonic of `B♭`. But that doesn't explain segments like `G♮ A♭ A♮`.

It could have been `G♮ G♯ A♮ B♭ B♮` to both use sharps for a rising chromatic line, and also maintain `B♭` for the tonality, but it wasn't written that way.

My point is old scores don't always follow the practice of sharps for rising chromatic lines. I think it is a more modern practice.

This doesn't explain why Beethoven used `G♮` when `Fx` makes more sense harmonically. But you can at least drop the "sharps for rising chromatic lines" part of the question, because apparently that was not always the practice.

I would guess `G♮` for the sake of white key convenience on piano, but that is easily contradicted by Beethoven solo piano scores, and the inconsistent spelling in the various instrumental parts.